# How to get method URL programmatically in SpringBoot test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, resttemplate

I would like to test my controller with

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MyTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    int port;

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate rest;

    String myUrl = ...;

    @Test
    public void testSequence() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        String requesString = ...
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>( requesString, headers );
        String response = rest.postForObject(myUrl, request, String.class);
```

here I need to hardcode `myUlr` with something like

```
 String.format("http://localhost:%d/my/endpint/path", port);
```

where `my/endpint/path` depends on annotations I applied to my controller class and it's methods.

But can I derive it programmatically having class name and method name?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could extract the `@RequestMapping` path from your REST controller using reflection and combine it with the path from a handler method in it, but it's really not worth the hassle and it is much easier to put them into public constants and use those to construct the resulting url in your test.

Also, constructing an url before testing it is actually a part of the test - you check that your api url looks like you expect it to.

Comment: Spring could have a method for this

Comment: Check out the Spring project's own tests: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b871a1e457832bb6ad46409bb3deb5b11d0fc684/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-actuator/src/test/java/smoketest/actuator/AbstractManagementPortAndPathSampleActuatorApplicationTests.java . Suppose they would have known if there was one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MvcUriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html)

Let's play with kittens:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/cats")
public class CatsController {

    @GetMapping("/childrenOf")
    public List<Cat> getChildrenOf(@RequestParam("mommy") String mommyName); //omitted

}



//import static omitted


{
    assertDoesNotThrow(()-> getMockMvc.perform(get(
        fromMethodCall(
            on(CatsController.class).getChildrenOf("luna")
        ).build().toUri()
    ))
}
```

The above results into `http://localhost/api/v1/cats/childrenOf/?mommy=luna`

I used line breaks and indentation heavily to prominently display the use of MvcUriComponentsBuilder